# Add menu item to media library

Tags: module, magento-1, media, code-reuse

I would like to add a menu item (in the admin panel) to a page which allows to manage pictures.
I found some interesting code in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Wysiwyg/` and in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/`.

But as I am very new to Magento, I don't know how to re-use this code.
Should I create a custom module and point the existing block in the `config.xml` ?